# Linking error -> Managed DLL to Unmanaged Lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a managed C++ dll which uses a unmanaged C++ lib. I've added the lib file in the managed project's "Additional Dependencies". Unfortunately I get a dozen of std::locale already defined in msvcprtd.lib linking errors.

Any idea? Do I have to build both as dll and link them together?

Comment: Have you checked what runtime library both of your projects are using?  Under C/C++ -> Code generation -> Runtime Library.  It might be unrelated, but whenever I get errors like this it's usually because of a runtime library mismatch.

Comment: I did. The dll managed project is Multi-threaded Debug Dll. Whereas the unmanaged lib is Multi-threaded Debug. Both looks good to me.

Comment: That is your problem then, they both need to match.  I'll elaborate in an answer.

Comment: I always thought that MT Debug DLL is for building DLL, and MT Debug is for building static libraries. I'm wrong?

Comment: Yeah, it's to set the version of the runtime library you link against, nothing to do with the type of project you are building.  See my answer for specifics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to change the runtime library setting for one of your projects so that they are both the same.  The "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" option in the runtime library settings means that your project will be linked against the DLL version of the runtime lirary, not that your project is a DLL.  Where-as "Multi-Threaded Debug" means it will link against a .lib version of the standard library.

When you link together 2 projects that use different settings, then they end up with duplicate references.  One reference from the static runtime library, and one from the DLL runtime library.  This is the source of your errors.

Which setting you should pick depends on whether you want to distribute the runtime DLLs with your project (or count on the user already having them).  If you want to go for this option, select the DLL runtime library, otherwise select the non-DLL version.  The down side of the non-DLL version is that all the runtime library code will be embedded in your DLL/EXE, which will increase it's size.

EDIT: Actually, looking into it a bit more.  [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) indicates that with CLR projects (which I suspect yours is, being managed C++) you can't use the static linked option, so you need to use the "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" option for both.